# how to differentiate between comments and replies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

SERVER SIDE: I have created 3 tables (comments,replies,tags) and I find that the problem is on the CLIENT SIDE: how can I tell that this comment is for this image and this reply is for this comment 
I created under each comment and image a hidden input that will hold the id of the image or the id of the comment but is it the cleanest way to do it or there is something else

I have no problem with database and php this is the way I do it and it is working good (comments,replies,tags) the problem is in the page will be shown to the user

Comment: Why not matching the class of comment and image (Probably you should have given the same class name for both)

Comment: @sulthan-allaudeens finlly some one understand T_T thanks,so from what you say I think there is no security issues if I put the hidden inputs

Comment: No it was never a security issue. Shall i tell a bit brief in answer ?

Comment: @sulthan-allaudeen yes of course

Comment: Answered the question. Kindly reply if you need further help :)

Comment: Adding +1 for your interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall do like this

Consider this as your html

On your loop to print the comments

For comment

```
<img src ="something.png" class="yourclass comment_123">
```

for reply

```
<img src ="something.png" class="yourclass comments_123 reply_123">
```

or

```
<img src ="something.png" class="yourclass 123">
```

On the click event (or any events) you just need to [slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) and take only the id. So that you can identify it belongs to which comment or reply.

**Note :**

1. Naming is your wish that you decide.
2. You can even do a hidden inputs and then calling in on some jquery events

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can add another field in the database table to save the type like 'image' or 'comment'. If it is image, then that field will be image else it will be 'comment'.

Comment: No I'm talking about the client side (javascript,html) how to mark each comment and image and reply to be known  after submitting I have no problem with (database,php)

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the replies table and add column "parent" into comments table, which will indicate parent comment ID. With that solution you can have also nested replies.